# Reconciling Features with different field types

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, tools

I have two feature classes who mostly have the same fields. However, some of the fields do not share the same field types. For example, one has a created date field that is a Date while the other feature class has a created date field that is a String. This is repeated on several fields with doubles, shorts, etc.. Normally, no problem, I can use a join and the field calculator.

However, these two feature classes represent before and after GPS data collection. So one feature might be a few feet off of it's counterpart. One last constraint is that the info and data must be migrated to one of the feature classes in it's existing database with existing relates. At least I think that is a constraint because the database is setup in a certain way to work with the surveying software.

Data needs migrated to this feature using the field types existing here:

[image]

Data from here needs migrated and in some cases converted between field types. Actual location from this one also needs to be used:

[image]

Are there any tools or recommendations to reconcile these two feature classes into a single feature class as described? I'm guessing it's going to be a painful multi-step process.

Comment: Can you join by FacilityIdentifier? is that field unique? Otherwise if you use spatial join there is an option for *closest* within a tolerance, that should get most of them *but* if you specify a tolerance too large you may join to the wrong GPS resolved point.

Comment: A spatial join probably will not work since there are clusters of points that could easily be snapped to the wrong location. Is there a way to snap points spatially using their FacilityIdentifier? That would solve half of it, then I could join based on location and copy the data over using the field calculator.